# How come the first <button> gets activated inside a form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a `<form>`
Inside that form, I have 2 submit buttons.

The first one is this:

```
<button  class="regular" id="geocodesubmit" style="height:40px;">Set Loc
ation</button>
```

The second one is this:

```
<button  type="submit" class="regular" name="Submit Discovery">Submit</button>
```

How come my first button gets activated when I push enter on one of the text boxes?  I want the 2nd one to activate...

I don't want the first one to respond to any keypresses.

Note: I don't want to use input type="submit", because I have a lot of other css stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML4 spec says that the default type of a `button` tag is `submit`.
See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

So your problem is simply the fact, that your first button doesn't have a `type` attribute and will therefore act like another submit button.

To fix it set `type="button"` for the first button.

Comment: Good answer, tested this in chrome and firefox and it actually works. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Then write onclick function for the both buttons respective to there uses. 
or else give name tags for buttons and do the required job inside the program

Answer (score 0):

it's

```
<input type="submit" class="regular" name="Submit Discovery">Submit</input>
```

not button

Comment: i didnt mean that button is invalid, i meant if you want to get the submit button to submit on enter you should use input, btw whats timex